# Shaders in Canvas based game - Android

Tags: android, 2d

My question is straight, can I apply shaders or some other tehnique to canvas based game (2d) on Android to make game that looks like sketch on paper.

I want to make kind of sketchy looking game, and I'm interested in how to do it ?

Comment: You can use GLSL and only use OpenGL to render 2D graphics (Orthographic projection)

Comment: Thank You for comment, but I think that using OpenGLES for simple 2d games is overhead...

Comment: I think that if you want to be able to use shaders or something like that, OpenGL ES is your best option.